# Getting Minecraft Images

Tags: javascript, minecraft

I am trying to make something, where, if you input your minecraft username, you get your profile icon.

I found this website Minotar, where you could get icons by the url. So, I tried making a JavaScript script out of it, and display it. But, the picture doesn't want to show up when I click "Go!".

What have I done wrong?

Here is my code.

```
<script>
function usernameget(){
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var url = "http://www.minotar.net/avatar/" + username + "/150";
  document.getElementById("usernamepicture").setAttribute("src", url);
}
</script>
<form>
  <img id="usernamepicture" src="">
  <p>Your Minecraft Username</p>
  <input type="text" id="username">
  <button onclick="usernameget()">Go!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: are u sure that the URL contains only an image and nothing else?

Comment: Remove the `form` tag.

Comment: @MohitBhasi I know the URL is correct. I've tried it. Anyway, I found the answer, so there's no worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set you button type to `button`.

```
<button onclick="usernameget()" type="button">Go!</button>
```

This will stop it from submitting your `form`.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/512p1L89/

---

However I think the better solution would be to remove the form tag unless you do require the user to later submit the form back to the server.